# How to have multiple gems that share the same common Ruby module?

Tags: ruby, module, rubygems

I've written a Ruby module, `common_services.rb`, which contains convenience methods for interfacing with a web service; I consider it a piece of common code.  Now, I would like to create two separate gems, both of which utilize the convenience methods in this module.  I visualize something like this:

```
rubyStuff/
  commonCode/
    common_services.rb  <-- common code lives here
  gemA/
    bin/
    lib/                <-- gemA would like to pull in common_services to use it
    gemA.gemspec
  gemB/
    bin/
    lib/                <-- gemB would also like to pull in common_services to use it
    gemB.gemspec
```

Each of gemA and gemB would have a reference to the common code in order to use it, for example `rubyStuff/gemA/lib/gemA/main.rb` might begin as:

```
require_relative '../../commonCode/common_services.rb'

puts CommonServices.getMessageOfTheDay()
<etc>
```

It's not working out too well for me, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this in Ruby.  One problem I'm having is with packaging a gem to reference a file that is *outside of its own path*:

```
s.files = Dir['bin/**'] + Dir['lib/**/*'] + Dir['../commonCode/**']
```

When using the .. notation in the gemspec, and trying to install the resulting gem, produces:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::PathError) installing into parent path /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/commonCode/common_services.rb of /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gemA-0.0.1 is not allowed
```

It makes sense to me why gems are not allowed to reach outside of their own path, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.  In Ruby, how and where should I organize Ruby code that will be used by multiple gems in my codeline, so that the multiple gems can use this common code?  Am I going about reuse entirely the wrong way?  Symbolic link magic?

Thanks for taking the time to read through this.

Comment: Seems like you need 3 gems. Pull out common_code into its own gem and have each of the other two pull it in. Doesn't really make sense to me to hard require a plain ruby file that lives outside of a gem.

Comment: I thought about that, but I wasn't sure:  is it common to have a stand-alone Ruby gem that does nothing on its own, except provide services for other gems?  Most gems i have used *do something*.  But I agree, that is a superior organization pattern for common code to what I have above.

Comment: I think it all depends on how significant each bit of code is. Is `common_code` really significant enough for its own gem? Or more importantly, perhaps, are gemA and gemB really different enough to merit there own gems? Perhap a single gem containing all three is better?

Comment: I see.  Yes, it's entirely appropriate for the common_code to have its own gem.  I omitted details to keep this question simple, but the common code is actually a library of functions for working with a 3rd-party vendor's web service API ... so it breaks off nicely into its own '3rd-party-vendor-utils' kind of gem.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing comments above for posterity...

There are a couple things to consider here. 
1. Is `commonCode` significant? Is it a good chunk of code, or just a few files? 
2. Are `gemA` and `gemB` significant? Should each of them really be gems?

Seems like you're in either one of two situations, depending on the significance of the code you've written:

1. `commonCode` is significant enough (amount of code, complexity, logical separation from `gemA` and `gemB`) to merit its own gem? If so, definitely pull it out into its own gem. You can require `gem-common` in the other two. It doesn't make sense to require a plain ruby file in `A` and `B` that lives outside of those two code bases.
2. `commonCode` is too insignificant to be pulled into its own gem. If this is the case, you should consider whether or not `gemA` and `gemB` really deserve their own gems, each. If they aren't big enough or logically separate enough, maybe all three can be combined into a larger gem.